# Need assistance in joining two data frames on column, which contains aggregated value

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In pyspark we are trying to join two data frames.
we are joining a data frame with another one  (which itself is generated by join )

```
result3 = result2.join(df3, df3.mktg_id == result2."max(acct_mkt_id)").select('result2.trans_dt', 'result2.channel','result2.loc_id','result2.meta_reason','max(acct_mkt_id)', 'max(campaign_name)').groupBy('result2.trans_dt', 'result2.channel','result2.loc_id','result2.meta_reason','max(acct_mkt_id)', 'max(campaign_name)').agg(sum("result2.bskt_sum"))
```

Error message

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

However, I am getting syntax error.
now result2.schema does have field max(acct_mkt_id) but if I try without quotes

```
result3 = result2.join(df3, df3.mktg_id == result2.max(acct_mkt_id)).select('result2.trans_dt', 'result2.channel','result2.loc_id','result2.meta_reason','max(acct_mkt_id)', 'max(campaign_name)').groupBy('result2.trans_dt', 'result2.channel','result2.loc_id','result2.meta_reason','max(acct_mkt_id)', 'max(campaign_name)').agg(sum("result2.bskt_sum"))
```

Error message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 842, in __getattr__
    "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'max'
```

Can you please let me know, what I am missing or how do I bypass this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`col`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#col-java.lang.String-) to refer to the column in cases such as this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

result2.col("max(acct_mkt_id)")
```

---

In PySpark you can simply refer to the column by:

```
result2["max(acct_mkt_id)"]
```